# I'm trying to make a full calendar and datepicker but what i'm getting is full calendar without date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to make a full calendar and datepicker but what i'm getting is full calendar without date picker on the left of the screen.

```
$(function() {
    $("#edit").click(function() {
        window.location = "${createLink(controller:'calendar',action:'edit', id:calendarInstance.id)}"; });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#calender").fullCalendar({
            // your options here
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var d = new Date(dateText);
                $('#calender').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
            }
        }
    }); 
}

<br/ 

<div id="calender"></div>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Is is right way of doing it?
I'm new on this matter.

Comment: your JS braces aren't correct in your sample code - there's one missing

Comment: @andy boot : thanx . i got my mistake earlier. Anyways thanx for posting the answer  :)